Unexplained Reindex ffill behavior yearend
I have a dataframe p of stock prices for trading days (when the market is open). When I go to re-index p for YE with method=ffill, 2023-12-31 will be front-filled with the value from 2023-12-29 (the last day of 2023 in my original sample), but it will be not front filled with the value from 2023-12-28 when 2023-12-29 is instead set to be NaN. Please explain this behavior so I understand what reindex is doing.
p['Stock A'].loc[pd.Timestamp(2023,12,25):].head(10)
2023-12-26    5.3418
2023-12-27    5.4445
2023-12-28    5.8143
2023-12-29    5.9273
2024-01-02       NaN
2024-01-03       NaN
Name: Stock A, dtype: float64

p['Stock A'].reindex(pd.DatetimeIndex(['2022-12-31', '2023-12-31', '2024-12-11'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None),method='ffill')
2022-12-31    14.4229
2023-12-31     5.9273
2024-12-11        NaN
Name: Stock A, dtype: float64

p['Stock B'] = p['Stock A']
p.loc[pd.Timestamp(2023,29,29), 'Stock B'] = np.nan
p['Stock B'].reindex(pd.DatetimeIndex(['2022-12-31', '2023-12-31', '2024-12-11'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None),method='ffill')
2022-12-31    14.4229
2023-12-31        NaN
2024-12-11        NaN
Name: Stock B, dtype: float64


The documentation mentions that "filling while reindexing does not look at dataframe values, but only compares the original and desired indexes." Because 2023-12-31 is missing from the original index, the function will frontfill from the last available index (2023-12-29) regardless of whether that value is present or NaN.
You can get the function to frontfill the 2023-12-28 value by executing p.drop(pd.Timestamp(2023,12,29)) rather than simply setting the 2023-12-19 value to be NaN.
